# Why do I get "Duplicate entry" exception when inserting a record?

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe7, firedac

I am getting this error message:

> [FireDAC][Phys][MySQL] Duplicate entry '1111' for key 'PRIMARY'

when trying to insert data into the database. The only data in the database is a tuple with the primary key '0000', so I know the primary key isn't a duplicate of another key. The data is inserted into the database correctly, so is there any way of stopping the error from popping up when the primary key isn't a duplicate ?

I am using Delphi XE7, MySQL 6.2, `FDConnection` and `FDQuery`. My code is:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
FDQuery1.SQL.Add(
  'Insert into Customer (' +
    'CustID,' +
    'Forename,' +
    'Surname,' +
    'Address,' +
    'PostCode' +
  ') ' +
  'Values (' +
    QuotedStr(CustID) + ',' + 
    QuotedStr(Forename) + ',' +
    QuotedStr(Surname) + ',' +
    QuotedStr(Address) + ',' +
    QuotedStr(Postcode) +
  ')'
);
FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
FDQuery1.Open;
```

Comment: I suspect that the `FDQuery1.Open;` call executes the `INSERT` query again. Why do you have it there ? Why don't you use parameters ? And why do you use `Clear` and `Add` if you can simply assign `Text`, or better yet, prepare the statement and keep it prepared changing only parameters and calling `ExecSQL` ?

Comment: Why do you specify an ID instead of relying on an auto-increment feature of MySQL?

Comment: Getting rid of the `FDQuery1.Open` worked thanks

Comment: Just to further clarify: `ExecSQL` is used for SQL statements that do **NOT** return a rowset, such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. `Open` is used for queries that **DO** return a rowset, such as `SELECT`. There will be **ZERO** instances where both are appropriate without changing the SQL between the method executions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing the same SQL statement twice. First with `ExecSQL`, then with `Open`. You should only use ***one or the other*** depending on whether your SQL statement actually returns any results.

In your case, you have written a simple `INSERT` query, so `ExecSQL` is the correct choice. Note that if you use `Open` with this query (without the `ExecSQL`) you would still get an error because there is "no data to open" (so to speak).

To emphasise the rule: *Use `Open` if the SQL statement returns data*. Here is an example where you would `Open` even when your statement inserts a row.

```
LQuery.SQL.Text :=
    'INSERT INTO Customer (CustId, CustomerName)'#13#10 +
    'VALUES ('+QuotedStr(ACustId)+','#13#10 +
               QuotedStr(ACustomerName)+');'#13#10 +
    'SELECT  CustId, CustomerName, DateAdded'#13#10 +
    'WHERE   CustId = '+QuotedStr(ACustId)
LQuery.Open;
```

As illustrated, you may want to return the new row immediately after insert if the database assigns any values (e.g. default values, auto-keys, rowversion). And if thats's the case, then you should use `Open`.

> SIDE NOTE: I've stuck with a dynamic query as per your question. However, it's generally advisable to go with a parametrised query or even stored procedure.